# 1 error prohibited this {{model}} from being saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Rails is showing the validation messages on the page as such:

```
1 error prohibited this {{model}} from being saved
There were problems with the following fields:
{{attribute}} {{message}}
```

Wanting it to show the model names not these these brackets.
How do I fix it and why's it doing this?

Comment: What version of Rails? What version of Ruby? What OS? What does your code look like? What else is in your logs? What does your Gemfile look like? etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a problem with internationalization in rails.  One solution that has worked for some is to downgrade the internationalization gem from 0.5.0 to 0.4.2, like so:

```
sudo gem uninstall i18n
sudo gem install i18n -v 0.4.2
```

Of course, if you're using RVM to manage your gems, you don't need `sudo` in the commands above.

Comment: Anyone have a link to the bug report which is producing this error? Just wanted to keep an eye on when this might be fixed. Cheers

Comment: It's not a bug per se :-( - it's because of the usual "break previous APIs" mentality with Rails development. Rails 3 tries to move to Ruby 1.9 and Ruby 1.9 includes a "%{}" syntax for string substitutions, so the i18n mechanism moved to that too. In the i18n gem, versions prior to 0.5.0 support both. At and after 0.5.0, only the new format is supported. Unfortunately, this means that you can accidentally break your Rails 2.3.5 installation by installing Rails 3, since it pulls in i18n 0.5.0.

Comment: Further to the above - at around about Rails 2.3.8, Rails itself started using the new interpolation syntax, so it works fine with the new i18n gem. But of course most people don't run anything after Rails 2.3.5, because they've all got critical faults due to their dependence on a broken Rack version (among other issues). See the Ruby On Rails blog and the user comments on e.g. the 2.3.9 release announcement for further details. Until Rails 2.3.x is working properly again, it's all a horrible mess.

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution involves using bundler to manage your gems instead of using the system defaults and the old Rails 2.x method of embedding it into environment.rb. Bundler segregates your application gems from your system gems properly and removes the problems that occur when using i18n versions 0.4.2 and 0.5 along with Rails 2.x and 3.x.

Steps:

1. Setup bundler for your Rails 2.3 app

   - http://gembundler.com/rails23.html
2. In your Gemfile, just completely leave out i18t.
3. Run 'bundle'

Note: If you do need i18n, just specify the correct version in the Gemfile. Bundler properly segregates your app's gems from your system gems so there will never be the strange behaviors of having both 0.4.2 and 0.5 installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to leave both gems installed, another solution is to create config/preinitializers.rb and add the line

```
gem 'i18n', '0.4.2'
```

Comment: the only gotcha to consider is that if using passenger with smart spawning (your apps shared an instance of rails) the preinitializer is ignored so you'll have to change a line in activesupport 2.3.5
activesupport-2.3.5/lib/activesupport/vendor.rb
from: gem 'i18n', '>= 0.1.3'
to: gem 'i18n', '>= 0.1.3' , '< 0.5.0'
All you are doing is telling active support that compatibility breaks starting with the 0.5.0 series

Answer (score 0):

While using Rails 2.3.5, even with config/preinitializers.rb containing

`gem 'i18n', '0.4.2`

and environment.rb containing

`config.gem "i18n", :version => '0.4.2'`

I had to uninstall version 0.5.0 of the i18n gem to make this work.